# using check box selected append textarea and update textarea value using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have problem in updating value of textarea.

when this checkbox is checked , it will show textarea. Now the problem is i am not able to add and save some more text in the textarea.

For example, as of now the textarea shows CBC value, but if i change it to CBC NEW, then it should be update to CBC NEW.

```js
('#contactform :checkbox.one_c').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(':checked')) {

    var newInput = $('<textarea  id="addme" class="doctor1 value" ><div id="c-content"></div></textarea>');

    $('#contactform').append(newInput);
    $("textarea").text("CBC");
    $('#contactform :checkbox.one_c').attr("checked", "checked");

  } else {
    $('#contactform').find('#addme').remove();
    $('#contactform :checkbox.one_c').removeAttr('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<form class="textboxes1" method="post" id="tb2_1964">
  <div id="contactform">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 remove_all">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline one_c" checked="checked">
        <label>CBC </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="addme" class="doctor1 value">CBC</textarea>
    <div id="c-content"></div>
  </div> <button class="patient_add2 no_print">Save</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem in your JS code. Try this hope this is helpful for you

```js
$('.one_c').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(':checked')) {

    var newInput = $('<textarea  id="addme" class="doctor1 value" ><div id="c-content"></div></textarea>');

    $('#contactform').append(newInput);
    $("textarea").text("CBC");
    $('#contactform :checkbox.one_c').attr("checked", "checked");

  } else {
    $('#contactform').find('#addme').remove();
    $('#contactform :checkbox.one_c').removeAttr('checked');
  }
});

$('.patient_add2').click(function(){
alert($("textarea").val());
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="textboxes1" method="post" id="tb2_1964">
  <div id="contactform">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 remove_all">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline one_c" checked="checked">
        <label>CBC </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="addme" class="doctor1 value">CBC</textarea>
    <div id="c-content"></div>
  </div> <button class="patient_add2 no_print">Save</button>

</form>
```